# Case sensitive query in yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2, case-sensitive

To find record in yii2 I use following code:

```
$response = Response::findOne(['unique_url' => $unique_url]);
```

But it return record regardless `$unique_url` case.
How to do it case sensitive?

Comment: What kind of database you are using?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with mySql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should use  `LIKE BINARY`

and for this you should extended you modelSearch adding the clause in query condition

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = YuorModel::find();      
    .......
    .......

    $query->andFilterWhere(['like binary', 'unique_url', $this->unique_url])
          ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'your_field2', $this->your_field2])
    .......
```

Comment: Thanks, find some shorter solution: $response = Response::find()->where('BINARY [[unique_url]]=:unique_url', ['unique_url'=>$unique_url])->one();

Comment: @DmitryBorovkov You can add this as another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Best solution which I found for this:

```
Response::find()->where('BINARY [[unique_url]]=:unique_url', ['unique_url'=>$unique_url])->one();
```